# Calcular média em C utilizando vetores

Tags: c, array

iniciei minha jornada no C há dois dias atrás. Fui tentar desenvolver uma função que calculava a média de determinados números de um vetor. A função está com algum problema já que era para retornar o valor de **4,5** e está retornando o valor de **4.00**. Será que alguém poderia me ajudar?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int mediaVetor(float vet[], int tam){
  float media, soma = 0;
  int i;

  for(i =0; i<tam; i++){
    soma = soma + vet[i];
  }
  media = (float) soma/tam;

  return media;
}

int main(){
  float vetor[6] = {3.0, 4.3, 5.6, 2.8, 7.9, 3.4};
  float resultado;

  resultado = mediaVetor(vetor, 6);
  printf("A media dos vetores e de %.2f\n", resultado);
}
```

Comment: O tipo de sua função deveria ser float e não int. float mediaVetor(float vet[], int tam){

Comment: Nossa, não tinha reparado nisso. Obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema está na declaração do mediaVetor. Ao invés de **int**, usa **float**. Como abaixo:

```
#include <stdio.h>

float mediaVetor(float vet[], int tam){
  float media, soma = 0;
  int i;

  for(i =0; i<tam; i++){
    soma = soma + vet[i];
  }
  media = (float) soma/tam;

  return media;
}

int main(){
  float vetor[6] = {3.0, 4.3, 5.6, 2.8, 7.9, 3.4};
  float resultado;

  resultado = mediaVetor(vetor, 6);
  printf("A media dos vetores e de %.2f\n", resultado);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

O tipo de retorno da função deve ser float. O cast em `media = (float) soma / tam` é desnecessário, pois o valor da operação já é um float.

```
#include <stdio.h>

float mediaVetor(float vet[], int tam) {
    float media, soma = 0;
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < tam; i++){
        soma += vet[i];
    }

    media = soma / tam;

    return media;
}

int main(){
    float vetor[6] = {3.0, 4.3, 5.6, 2.8, 7.9, 3.4};
    float resultado;

    resultado = mediaVetor(vetor, 6);
    printf("A media dos vetores e de %.2f\n", resultado);
}
```